# Retrieving a max date from DB2 in Java throwing wrong column type conversion exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, type-conversion

I have the following SQL that returns the max BILL_DATE based on some criteria. BILL_DATE is defined in the database as a DATE.

```
SELECT MAX(BILL_DATE)
FROM BILLTABLE
WHERE col1 = ? and
      col2 = ?
```

But when I read the value from the resultSet.

```
bill.setBillDate(resultSet.getDate(1));
```

An exception is thrown:

> Invalid data conversion: Wrong result column type for requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

I have also tried

```
bill.setBillDate(resultSet.getString(1));
```

But that doesn't return a date. It returns either `100`, `200` or `300` which is obviously not correct.

Is there another way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you see if you print out getString(1)? How are you defining the date field in your table?

Comment: I have updated my question reflecting your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two resultSets open in the function where I was reading in the BILL_DATE. I changed the code to the following and it works fine.

```
bill.setBillDate(resultSet1.getDate(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ash is right, how are you defining the date column?

Is it possible the column is timestamp?  In that case try resultSet.getTimestamp(1))